# Why does custom-bib produce this error? Long URLs and 'You can't pop an empty literal stack...' solutions don't work for my BibTeX Style

Tags: url, custom-bib

would be nice if someone could help out. I am finishing up my thesis and realized that the usual BibTeX styles are not what I am looking for. I want to cite Nature Magazine style. I used custom-bib to do so and it works fine for journal articels but produces a few problems:

1. URLs don't break, they go centimeters into the right margin. I tried solutions but they didn't work.
2. The 'You can't pop an empty literal stack...' error is present for three citations and I have no clue why.
3. URLs get always included when I only want them for some citations, how can I do adjust that?

Here is a mwe:

```
 \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, BCOR=10mm, german, nenglish]{scrbook}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, style=super, nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\usepackage[unicode=true,bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,
                bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,breaklinks=false,
                pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]{hyperref}


\makeglossaries

\glsresetall

\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Errors in bibTeX}
\author{TeXStruggler}
\date{June 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum\cite{CreZeichung}\cite{Hoxb8Slitrk1}\cite{FateMappingHistoryOverview}

\bibliographystyle{NatureDiploma}
\bibliography{introduction}

\end{document}
```

Here are the problematic entries:

```
@misc{CreZeichung,
  title={Lineage tracing in stem cells using Cre-LoxP system},
  author={Marini, Grazia},
  page={bioRender},
  note = {accessed 1 p.m. on January 4th, 2020},
  url = {https://app.biorender.com/community/gallery/s-5ebc725a6886a700ab441051-lineage-tracing-in-stem-
  cells-using-cre-loxp-system},
  year={2020}
}

@incollection{Hoxb8Slitrk1,
  title={Mouse models of neurodevelopmental disease of the basal ganglia and associated circuits},
  author={Pappas, Samuel S and Leventhal, Daniel K and Albin, Roger L and Dauer, William T},
  booktitle={Current Topics in Developmental Biology},
  volume={109},
  pages={97--169},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@incollection{FateMappingHistoryOverview,
title = "Chapter Ten - Genetic Fate Mapping Using Site-Specific Recombinases",
editor = "Paul M. Wassarman and Philippe M. Soriano",
series = "Methods in Enzymology",
publisher = "Academic Press",
volume = "477",
pages = "153 - 181",
year = "2010",
booktitle = "Guide to Techniques in Mouse Development, Part B: Mouse Molecular Genetics, 2nd Edition",
issn = "0076-6879",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0076-6879(10)77010-5",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0076687910770105",
author = "Emilie Legué and Alexandra L. Joyner",
abstract = "Understanding how cells are assembled in three dimensions to generate an organ, or a whole organism, is a pivotal question in developmental biology. Similarly, it is critical to understand how adult stem cells integrate into an existing organ during regeneration or in response to injury. Key to discovering the answers to these questions is being able to study the various behaviors of distinct cell types during development or regeneration. Fate mapping techniques are fundamental to studying cell behaviors such as proliferation, movement, and lineage segregation, as the techniques allow precursor cells to be marked and their descendants followed and characterized over time. The generation of transgenic mice, combined with the use of site-specific recombinases (SSR) in the mouse genome, has provided a means to develop powerful genetic fate mapping approaches. A key advantage of genetic fate mapping is that it allows cells to be genetically marked, and therefore the mark is transmitted to all the descendants of the initially marked cells. By making modifications to the SSRs that render their enzymatic activity inducible, and the development of an assortment of reporter alleles for marking cells, increasingly sophisticated genetic fate mapping studies can be performed. In this chapter, we review the four main genetic fate mapping methods that utilize intrachromosomal recombination to mark cells (cumulative, inducible, clonal, and intersectional) and one interchromosomal method, the tools required to carry out each approach, and the practical considerations that have to be taken into account before embarking on each type of genetic fate mapping study."
}
```

Here's my custom-bib .bst file (It didn't fit in here): https://github.com/LaTeXStruggler/NatureStyle/blob/828a463f980402aea82c767b33db24c834a00264/Problems

I hope somebody is good at editing these bsts. I tried for hours on-end and I just can't figure out how to solve these. Otherwise I think the Bibliography looks great

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just found out the error only arises with the incollection citations. For articles and books it is fine. If nothing works, I'll change it to book. Ugly but works. For the URL problem, I can't find a solution.

Comment: Did you by any chance hand-edit the bst file after creating it with the `makebst` utility? If so, what did you change? For instance, did you hand-edit code blocks that pertain to how the `year` field is displayed?

Comment: Hey Mico, thank for chimimg in. In the version I uploaded, I left it unchanged. I tried some of the year and months suggestions from other threads but they did not fix it. I found solutions for the URL stuff now. And for the other thing, it at least prints what I want it to look like, but the error persists. If I can't fix it, I'll give up and leave the error in it.

Comment: The reason I asked about the custom bst file possibly having received further manual edits is because the output of the `makebst` utility is usually bullet-proof. When I ran your code with the custom bst file contained in the link you provided, I also got the warning and error messages you say you've been encountering, and the `year` and `month`-related information simply looks odd. By the way, if you're willing to let linebreaks occur anywhere in a long URL string, all you need to do is load the `xurl` package (before loading `hyperref`, in case you also load `hyperref`).